# Eclipse Photon cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency

Tags: eclipse

On Windows 10 I upgraded from Eclipse Oxygen to Photon a few days ago. Today I asked it to check for updates, and it told me this:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Eclipse XML Editors and Tools 3.10.0.v201804210200 (org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group 3.10.0.v201804210200)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools 3.9.0.v201803221834 (org.eclipse.jst.web_ui.feature.feature.group 3.9.0.v201803221834)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    DTD Editor infopops 1.0.400.v201707252002 (org.eclipse.wst.dtd.ui.infopop 1.0.400.v201707252002)
    DTD Editor infopops 1.0.400.v201309112106 (org.eclipse.wst.dtd.ui.infopop 1.0.400.v201309112106)
    DTD Editor infopops 1.0.400.v201711201733 (org.eclipse.wst.dtd.ui.infopop 1.0.400.v201711201733)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools 3.9.0.v201803221834 (org.eclipse.jst.web_ui.feature.feature.group 3.9.0.v201803221834)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.wst.ws_ui.feature.feature.group [3.8.1.v201803221834,3.8.1.v201803221834]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Web Services Tools 3.8.1.v201803221834 (org.eclipse.wst.ws_ui.feature.feature.group 3.8.1.v201803221834)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group [3.9.2.v201803221834,3.9.2.v201803221834]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse XML Editors and Tools 3.10.0.v201804210200 (org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group 3.10.0.v201804210200)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.wst.dtd.ui.infopop [1.0.400.v201711201733,1.0.400.v201711201733]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse XML Editors and Tools 3.9.2.v201803221834 (org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group 3.9.2.v201803221834)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.wst.dtd.ui.infopop [1.0.400.v201707252002,1.0.400.v201707252002]
```

Before this I get an error `'Searching alternate solutions…' has encountered a problem.` with `No remedy found` in the dialog.

What do I do now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used a virgin installation (i.e. just an unzip of a download) of Eclipse Oxygen 3a, and after successfully upgrading from Oxygen 3a to Photon I replicated your *conflicting dependency* problem when doing **Check for Updates**. A similar error has [already been reported](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/error/report/4164522). The solution that worked for me is:

- **Help > Install New Software...**, then set **Work with** to http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/photon/
- A list of **Available Software** is instantly shown. Select **Web Tools Platform (WTP)**, or other option(s) as appropriate, depending on your existing Eclipse environment. Take a screen shot so you know the correct version to expect for each product after the installation.

  [image: install1]
- Click **Next >** to start installation. Don't be discouraged by the messages *"Cannot perform operation. Computing alternate solutions, may take a while... "*. Eventually you should see an **Install Remediation Page**. Change the selected option from **Keep my installation the same...** to **Update my installation...**.

  [image: install2]
- Click **Next >** and the **Install Details** screen will be shown, listing the name and version of each item to be installed. **Click Next >**, accept terms and click **Finish**. Eventually you will be invited to restart Eclipse.
- After the restart **Help > About > Installation Details > Installed Software** should now show the same versions that were captured in your earlier screen shot. In particular, the items that you had problems upgrading earlier using **Check for Updates** (*Eclipse Web Developer Tools* and *Eclipse XML Editors and Tools*) have been upgraded to version 3.10:

  [image: postInstall]
- As final sanity checks:

  - **Help > Check For Updates** should now report *"No updates were found"*.
  - Open Eclipse's **Error Log**. There should be no errors following the final restart.

Notes:

1. I find it comforting to have the **Progress** view open while performing the updates to see that changes really are being made when the upgrade seems frozen.
2. I compared the items in my Oxygen-3a-to-Photon upgrade with those in a virgin install of Photon, and they are not identical. That's hardly surprising, and not really a concern unless you hit new problems.
3. I'm guessing that you might get variations in the details described above if upgrading a used and modified installation of Eclipse Oxygen 3a, rather than the clean version which I used.
4. You might consider just migrating to a fresh install of Photon rather than upgrading Oxygen, though I realize that approach might be a real pain with respect to customized configuration and plugins.
5. Finally, [note this somewhat ominous warning from Eclipse](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/photon/): *"Updating from Oxygen to Photon **should work but is not extensively tested** for all features"*. Ugh!

---

7/14/18 Updates and clarifications:

- The WTP 3.10.0 upgrade involves the removal of "Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools" which "*[adds support for JSP files (but not Java Servlets), and complete support for "dynamic" web projects requires the full Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools Feature](https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#What_version_of_Eclipse_does_WTP_work_with.3F)*". I can't find any formal documentation on the removal, but two new features are added in WTP 3.10.0: "*Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools User Documentation*" and "*Eclipse Java Web Development Core*".
- On an Eclipse instance that had been upgraded from Oxygen to Photon, and then had WTP upgraded to 3.10.0, I created and debugged a servlet using Tomcat 9.0.10. JSPs also work. No issues were found (though obviously that doesn't mean there aren't any).
- The two screenshots below show matches filtered by "**Web**" in **Installed Software** on the screen **Help > About Eclipse IDE > Installation Details > Installed Software**. The first is for an Eclipse instance which was originally on Oxygen 3a, but was upgraded to Photon. The second is for a Photon instance created by unzipping a Photon download. Note that "**Java Web Developer Tools**" exists in the unzipped Photon instance, but not the instance upgraded from Oxygen.

[image: OxygenToPhotonInstalledSoftware]

[image: PhotonInstalledSoftware]

Comment: Well you certainly did a fantastic job of explaining your answer and walking me through the process! I don't have time to look at it closely at the moment, but I wanted to congratulate you and up-vote the answer. I'll go through it slowly and digest it before the bounty expires. I welcome input from others as well on their experiences and why we have the problem to begin with. Thanks!

Comment: "I compared the items in my Oxygen-3a-to-Photon upgrade with those in a virgin install of Photon, and they are not identical." I'd be interested in knowing what exactly is different. Is there an extra installed package? Is one missing? Is one package outdated?

Comment: skomisa, after reading your response more closely, I see that essentially your approach just uses the Eclipse remediation process, which _requests that you remove Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools_. I had got this far before. But do I want to remove Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools? Will that prevent me from running Tomcat and debugging servlets within Eclipse? Is Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools being replaced with something else in Photon, and if so, is there an official notice of this somewhere? So I'm afraid this solution won't work unless I know the implications of removing this package.

Comment: *"I'd be interested in knowing what exactly is different."* => That's beyond the scope of an answer on SO, but I've updated my answer with two relevant screens shots for "web" software.

*"I had got this far before"* => I disagree. The OP problem arises precisely because a WTP item (Eclipse XML Editors and Tools) could not be updated to 3.10.0 because another WTP item, Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools (JWDT), had not been removed first. The approach in my answer works because it removes all existing WTP items before upgrading.

Comment: *"But do I want to remove Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools?"* => That's not really the question to ask. Instead, ask *"Do I want to upgrade to Photon/WTP 3.10.0, or remain on Oxygen3a/WTP 3.9.x?"? If you want to upgrade Oxygen to Photon then you must use WTP 3.10.0, and the upgrade process will remove JWDT. And if you want to run Oxygen3a then you must use WTP 3.9.x, and JWDT is present. It's one or the other, but you can't upgrade to Photon and retain JWDT; that makes no sense. However, see my updated answer regarding a clean install of Photon which has JWDT in two places.

Comment: *"So I'm afraid this solution won't work unless I know the implications of removing this package."* => I understand your concern, but that approach may be self-defeating since [the Eclipse documentation on the WTP upgrade process is pretty thin](https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F). Ultimately, all that should matter is whether the WTP 3.0.10 upgrade works for you, and I urge you to try it and test it, initially using a new virgin instance of Oxygen3a rather than any existing instance. An alternative approach is to migrate to a clean install of Photon.

Comment: @GarretWilson I raised Eclipse [**Bug 537090 - WTP 3.10.0 upgrade does not include Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools with Eclipse**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=537090) for the discrepancies between upgrading to WTP 3.10.0 and using an unzipped version of Photon containing WTP 3.10.0.

Comment: @GarretWilson Also see Eclipse [**Bug 536431 - Cannot upgrade Eclipse Oxygen JEE to Eclipse Photon JEE**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=536431) for the issue raised in the OP. Note that the response states _"Update mechanism works in the vast majority of cases. But it's indeed not a path that all project test properly enough to make it work for them. So while it's expected to work, such glitches can still happen"_.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Eclipse may be abandoning upgrades for version jumps. As @skomisa noted, http://download.eclipse.org/releases/photon/ mentions that:

> Updating from Oxygen to Photon should work but is not extensively tested for all features.

And http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2018-09/ says something similar:

> Updating from Photon to 2018-09 should work but is not extensively tested for all features.

Similar problems as happened here occurred trying to get a fix for [Eclipse Bug 536806](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=536806). Eventually the appearance of new files made the upgrade go smoothly.

The discussion of that bug mentioned that Eclipse is moving to "a cadence of a full release every 3 months". Perhaps with a more rapid release schedule, Eclipse is caring less about certain upgrades. Whatever the case, I wish they would clarify their policy, instead of saying that "it may work" when they haven't even tests the simplest of upgrade scenarios.

Comment: [This blog post](http://blog.joda.org/2018/07/upgrading-to-eclipse-photon.html) stated that upgrading to Photon _"all went pretty well"_! But the author also described his approach to upgrading Eclipse, where the settings and configuration were [specified on GitHub](https://github.com/jodastephen/eclipse-setup). The specifics are probably not of much interest, but always being able to recreate an Eclipse environment by going to a single place is appealing. Given our Eclipse upgrade concerns, that might make version jumping (rather than constantly upgrading) a more attractive option.