# Getting a fix for ClosedFileSystemException bug with "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" package

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Windows 10. I am using the final release Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9) with the **"Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers"** package.

Unfortunately this version has a bug that produces a `ClosedFileSystemException` in some situations. This problem was filed as [Eclipse Bug #539536](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=539536) and marked as resolved. Unfortunately the discussion on that ticket isn't clear to me regarding how I am supposed to update my **"Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers"** to include the bug fix.

(Perhaps the ticket is clear but my mind is a little slow. If so, please indulge me while I ask some very specific questions; I get confused easily with ambiguous answers. I'll mark the questions in italics so they will stand out.)

1. I went to the [Eclipse 2018-12 M1 download page](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2018-12/m1), but there was no **"Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers"** package there. *Is the **"Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers"** package for Eclipse 2018-12 M1 available for download somewhere, and if so, where?*
2. A comment on Bug #539536 indicated that I can add http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.10milestones/ as an update site and then use "Check for Updates" to fix this bug. *Should I expect that this update site will update my **"Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers"** to the full 2018-12 M1 release, after which my Eclipse will show "2018-12 (4.10) M1", or will it only update one or more "features"?*
3. *If http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.10milestones/ will not update my version of Eclipse to 4.10 M1, then why does the URL include "4.10milestones"?*
4. By using "Check for Updates" after adding the http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.10milestones/ update site, I was able to update to "Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.16.0.…", "Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment 3.13.300.…", and "Tip of the Day UI Feature 0.2.200.…". *Does installing one or more of these updates fix Bug #539536 (the `ClosedFileSystemException` bug)—does my **"Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers"** now have the fix for Bug #539536?*

Thank you very much in advance for your time and clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answers to the separate questions below:

1. I don't know why the Java EE package is missing in 2018-12 M1 (the [2018-12 M1 announcement](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/epp-dev/msg05300.html) on the [epp-dev mailing list](https://accounts.eclipse.org/mailing-list/epp-dev) just says why the modeling package is missing; you might ask on this mailing list or in the [EPP forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/69/) why also the 2018-12 M1 Java EE package is missing), but if you don't want to wait for 2018-12 M2, you can download [**a current build** directly from Jenkins](https://ci.eclipse.org/packaging/job/simrel.epp-tycho-build/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/org.eclipse.epp.packages/archive/) which might not be as stable as the milestone builds and which are intended **for testing**.
2. **No**, because this is the milestone 4.10 **update site of the Eclipse Project** (Platform, JDK and PDE), not of the simultaneous release. The Eclipse simultaneous release 2018-12 staging update site is http://download.eclipse.org/staging/2018-12/. The [Eclipse Packing Project (EPP)](http://www.eclipse.org/epp/) builds the *Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers* from features from different Eclipse projects ([Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/), [JGit](http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/), [EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/), [WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/), etc.).
3. *4.10* is the upcoming version of the Platform, JDK and PDE. In contrast, ***2018-12*** is the version of the upcoming **simultaneous release** (which will contain also e. g. JGit/EGit 5.2 and therefore uses the different version scheme).
4. If you mean *Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.**16**.0.v20181010-1800* and not *Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.**1.6**.0.…*, **yes**. The last part of the version number tells you when it was built (here: 10 October 2018, at 6 p.m.). The changes regarding **[Eclipse bug 539536](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=539536) should be included**.

I would **recommend updating only the JDT feature** instead of the whole product/package. The aggregation of the different parts from different projects into one package might be buggy, especially with early milestone builds when new features are added and larger changes are made.

In addition, if you use the **Eclipse (Platform/JDT) project milestone update site** instead of the simultaneous release staging update site, you **get the changes at least four days earlier** because the [Eclipse project has an offset of "+0", while other projects have an offset up to "+3" days and the aggregation of the packages by EPP takes place on "+4"](https://wiki.eclipse.org/SimRel/Overview).

Comment: First of all, a sincere thanks for answering the individual questions succinctly!! The answers were very understandable and everything is a lot clearer now. As soon as this question is eligible for a bounty, I'll add one so I can show my appreciation. More responses below.

Comment: "If you Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.16.0.v20181010-1800….": Indeed, the version number was a typo. I've corrected it, thanks. And most of all, it's great news that this update fixes the bug; it wasn't clear to me, with so many milestone versions, plugin versions, update sites, features, etc. flying around. (That's one benefit of simply releasing a patch version, which I wish Eclipse would do.) Thanks again for the clarification.

Comment: "No, because this is the milestone 4.10 update site of the Eclipse Project…." Ah, I see. This was confusing as well, as in the past (for years, if not a decade) I had upgraded the entire Eclipse version using an update site. Since M1 wasn't available on the site for my package, I thought this would update my package to M1. I see that was an incorrect assumption. I guess there's no way to get the Java EE package for 2018-12 M1, neither from the site nor from an update, as far as I can tell.

Comment: "I don't know why the Java EE package is missing in 2018-12 M1…." Nobody seems to know, and it's a recurring thing. In fact the 2018-09 RC1 release candidate page didn't even have a Java EE build until after the final release!! (It's there now.) So it proves sort of frustrating when the "final" builds have big bugs and it's unclear how which thing actually contains the fix when the new builds aren't available for Java EE. Once again, thank you for clarifying everything here for Bug #539536.

Comment: Thanks for asking. I have extended the answer regarding your comments. My experience is that reported bugs are also fixed (e.g. [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=535504)). However, Eclipse is used very differently, so it is important that the pre-releases are also tested by many different people. So thanks also for using pre-releases and reporting bugs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the bounty. Eclipse is mainly developed by developers who use Eclipse to develop Eclipse-based applications. Therefore, bugs in the Java EE support are more easily overlooked. So please continue to report bugs to Eclipse and to ask questions about Eclipse. ;-)

Comment: I think Eclipse does a reasonable job responding to bugs submitted on Bugzilla. Unfortunately I think Eclipse has completely dropped the ball in the release process. It's impossible to figure out how to upgrade just to get a simple bug fixed, as illustrated here. See the conflicting advice at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52622066/421049 . See another example at https://stackoverflow.com/q/51234754/421049 . See previous examples at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=536806 . etc. You don't need to reply; just please understand that Eclipse still needs official patch releases.

Comment: Update: The [2018-12 M2 Java EE package (which has been renamed to _Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers_) is available](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2018-12/m2/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-developers). Information about the simultaneous releases builds can be found also on the [_cross-project-issues-dev_ mailing list](https://accounts.eclipse.org/mailing-list/cross-project-issues-dev) (beside on the already mentioned [_epp-dev_ mailing list](https://accounts.eclipse.org/mailing-list/epp-dev)) .

Comment: Thank you, @howlger! I was just about to mention this myself. I finally got some answers on [Bug 539339](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=539339), which provides a clue of maybe why they didn't include EE/Enterprise packages for some releases, and [Bug 540983](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=540983), which reaffirms that the EE/Enterprise package is now (finally!!) available for 2018-12 M2, which makes me happy (and relieved).